# Find classes implementing interface in PreApplicationStartMethod

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have the situation where I cannot edit the global.asax yet I need to wire up a ServiceStack service. I'm using `PreApplicationStartMethod` which works well but where it gets interesting is I need to allow other developers to plugin their own services in to my service.

In case they have their own APIs defined within their assembly, I've created an interface they can implement; my thinking is I can find the assemblies by looking for classes which implements that and pass it to ServiceStack. This also works well.

The issue however is using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` which only loads those dlls which are referenced (which won't be the case) so I looked at using `BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()` instead but I can't do that within `PreApplicationStartMethod` as it throws an error:

```
This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase.
```

Does anyone know how I can work around this? Or use Application_Start? I have included my code below in case it helps:

```
    private static Assembly[] GetServicesFromAssemblies()
    {
        var serviceType = typeof(IUCommerceApiService);
        var assemblies = GetAssemblies();
        return  assemblies
                    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                    .Where(serviceType.IsAssignableFrom)
                    .Select(t => t.Assembly)
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToArray();
    }

    // Works until app pool refresh
    private static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    }

    // Throws error when called within PreApplicationStartMethod
    private static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        return new ReadOnlyCollection<Assembly>(BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>().ToList());
    }
```

Comment: So other developers, when given your code, wireup to events you specify? Why not simply expose a method to register a type implementing interface A to your type?

Comment: No they don't wire up to events, we need to have their services registered in our API so all methods are available on one EndPoint

Comment: Correct, so why don't you simply expose a `public void RegisterService(IUCommerceApiService apiService)` method on your object, and then people using your code invoke that method within their own setup code? Or am I missing something?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, ServiceStack can't register additional methods after the EndPoint has been registered